# Xcode project files always modified when committing

Tags: xcode, git, gitignore

I have problems with git using Xcode for my iOS project.
I'm using CocoaPods for my dependencies. Everytime I click "commit" I have some modified files  listed (mainly from Pods directory) although I added Pods to my .gitignore and I did not make any changes to these files since the last commit.

Despite that they are always marked as "M" and ticked off even seconds after the last commit.
It is worth noting that I don't see any visible changes in the comparison view in those files[image].

Can someone please explain what happens and how to fix it?

Comment: Clearly you are not actually ignoring them. M means you did in fact commit them at some point.